# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'system' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-models

Although there is a discussion about this question I cannot find the solution to my problem.

I have some applications in a project. In the model of application A, namely "Test" I have a table "systems" and a table "Detail". In the views of application B, namely "task1b" I want to make queries on this models and show the results in a template. 
After importing Test.models I can make queries in "Detail" model, but not in "system".
In particular:

```
#Application: task1b, views.py
from Test.models import *
def task1ba(request):
    systems=system.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("Task1B-A.html", {"systems":systems}, RequestContext(request))
```

If I put Detail instead of "system" then I have no error. 
Using this model I had no problem in the past.
Trying to query any other model works instead of "system". Do you think it is a name problem? Any ideas accepted.

Comment: Please add output of this code: `from Test import models; print dir(models)` (general advice: don't use `import *`, better specify things you want to import instead).

Comment: The output is: ['Article', 'Detail', 'User', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'eval_meas', 'models', 'post_save', 'system', 'test_result', 'test_result_file', 'upload_information', 'user_profile']

Comment: That's strange. My guess is there's somewhere another variable named `system`, because it's  and it's unbound. You can try to import `system` with different alias: `from Test.models import system as AliasedSystem`, it might help. If not, what says output of `print locals()` and `print globals()` in this view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in yedpodtrzitko's comment, I think that the `import *` is at the root of the problem you're seeing. When importing everything from Test.models, one imports everything that it imports, which can give unexpected results.

The following can serve as some help with regard to using explicit imports:
[pep8 import docs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Using an explicit import in the above code would look like:

```
from Test.models import system

systems = system.objects.all
```

However, it seems likely that the name 'system' is conflicting with the system function call from the Python standard library os package shown here:

[python os.system documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

It is conventional to use the CapWords convention for python class names, so it would likely be appropriate to use 'System' as a name for your Django model, as opposed to 'system', unless the code presented above contains a typo, and the model is already declared as `class System(...`.

In other words, 'system' is likely shadowing a built-in function call, so a rename should be helpful if needed.

The amended code would be:

```
#Application: task1b, views.py
from Test.models import System
def task1ba(request):
    systems=System.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("Task1B-A.html", {"systems":systems}, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: It worked. Probably a conflict between the names, although I am not quite sure yet. Thanks..